# Embedding play-services when using android-sdk-plugin+sbt

Tags: android, google-maps, scala, sbt

I have a Scala Android app, build with SBT and the android-sdk-plugin.

I need to include the Google play-services library, for using the Google Maps API v2.  It contains resources and code.

After reading [the android-sdk-plugin doc](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin), I've seen this:

```
Using the google gms play-services aar:

libraryDependencies +=
  "com.google.android.gms" % "play-services" % "3.1.36"
```

I've done so, but when compiling my app through sbt, I receive this error:
    AndroidManifest.xml:34: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

For me, this is a clear symptompt that the resources of play-services aren't included.  They must be referenced from the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name="...">
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
  ...
</application>
```

With Gradle, I haven't had this problem, with the same AndroidManifest.xml and dependencies setup.

I've tried also to use the [android-plugin](http://fxthomas.github.io/android-plugin/tutorial/annex-b-cookbook.html) way of doing this with no success.  The aarlib() syntax is not understood by android-sdk-plugin.

What is the right way of using play-services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it is due to not specifiying well the right version.

I've used this:

```
"com.google.android.gms" % "play-services" % "4.+"
```

instead of this:

```
"com.google.android.gms" % "play-services" % "4.2.42"
```

The .+ notation isn't smart enough :-(

You can list avaialable versions by looking at the contents of this folder:

```
android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
```

Comment: can u post che Build.scala?

Comment: I'm using build.sbt instead.  The relevant part is already shown.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to go to the SDK manager and install "Google Repository" as well as "Android Support Repository".

Before doing that, `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/m2repository/` didn't exist.

I also added

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.android.gms" % "play-services" % "4.4.52"
```

to my `build.sbt`, and since I was upgrading from an earlier version had to delete `lib/google-play-services.jar` and `lib/android-support-v4.jar` as otherwise they were getting included twice.